# Integrating Matlab with C++

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, visual-c++, system-integration

I need to localize facial landmarks as a part of my research project and planning to use Supervised Descent Method (SDM) for that. Both the C++ and Matlab versions are available at the following site  and when I contacted them they said C++ version is not going to be available until they secure it. So, I had no other option and had to opt for Matlab version.

http://www.humansensing.cs.cmu.edu/intraface/download_functions_matlab.html

The problem is that My project is in C++ and OpenCV. I wonder whether  there is  a way to access Matlab version of SDM in Visual C++ . I mean, is there an integration mechanism available for that ?

And, the next issue is when executing the "Facial Feature Detection" code available at the above site I get the following error.
I executed it as given below.

[detected_points] = xx_track_detect(Model,[],image,[],options);

and, it says "undefined function or variable named 'model' "

anyone have a solution to this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need to use [Matlab engine](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/calling-matlab-engine-from-c-c-and-fortran-programs.html) to be able to execute Matlab commands from C++. The engine interface allows you to do just so.

Regarding the `model` variable - it is probably a representation of the learned model for facial landmarks, it should be supplied with the packge or you need to tune it by yourself. Without additional information I suggest you contact the publishers of the package for more information.